# Apache Drill - Clear Parquet Metadata Cache?

Tags: apache-drill

Is it possible to clear the parquet metadata cache in Apache Drill?

I'm finding that when you version files and use maxdir(), it holds on to old versions which may be deleted.

It seems like there should be a "clear metadata cache" command to cancel out the "refresh metadata cache" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in Drill so far.
Please log Jira for improvement [1]. Contributions always welcome.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL

Comment: Thanks for the info, created one just now:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6194

Comment: Till this feature is available, you may manually delete parquet metadata files with file pattern '.drill.parquet*' from parent and partition directories of a table.